# How to pass a react component trough a parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an App component witch contains two child: A navbar and a container.
When I click on a li on the navbar I'm passing a react component trough the parent, but it doesen't wrok.

App:

```
function App() {
  const [appState, setAppState] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log(appState);
    }, [appState])

  return (  
    <div className="App">
      <Nav stateSetter={setAppState}/>
      <Container state={appState}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Navbar:

```
function Nav(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="Nav" id="nav">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><button><span>App</span></button></li>
                        <li><button onClick={() => props.stateSetter("")}>Home</button></li>
                        <li><button onClick={() => props.stateSetter("")}>Products</button></li>
                        <li><button onClick={() => props.stateSetter("")}>About Us</button></li>
                        <li><button onClick={() => props.stateSetter(<Login />)}>Log in</button></li> 
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I only made the passing with the Login.

Container:

```
function Container(props) {
    const [renders, setRenders] = useState(props.state);
    console.log(renders);
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="container">
                {renders}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Please can you show the code for the `useState` function?

Comment: In which component? I think I do not understand you :(

Comment: in your `App` component you have `const [appState, setAppState] = useState();` Without understanding what `useState` is or does, I have no idea what `appState` or `setAppState` will be, and these in turn are what determine what happens when you click on one of your list items.

Comment: @RobinZigmond `useState` is a built in hook as part of react core as of version 16.8 - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: @BudaÖrs: in `Container`, it looks like you're only setting your `renders` state to `props.state` when the component is initialized. That state won't subsequently be changed if `props.state` changes. Are you sure you need `useState` in `Container`? You could just render `props.state` instead. (I'd recommend changing these names, by the way)

Comment: thanks @BrettEast, React hooks is something I haven't looked into yet. I guess I should have googled first, I just assumed it was a function specific to the OP's app.

Comment: Yes because I'm passing the React object to it. The object will be displayed there.

Comment: Have you considered using [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/) for this? It seems like rendering components based on passing app state would become messy really fast

Comment: I don't know what React Router is.

Comment: It will basically allow you to render components based off the url without having to pass components around.

Comment: I don't want to use the URL as an indicator. I would rather like to pass a react object through a parent. 

I have't leaned how to use URLs yet, so I would prefer to use useState.

Comment: @Jacob how do I change the content in Container if the appState changes?

Comment: @BudaÖrs: when you pass new props to the component, it'll re-render.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

State is preserved for the "same" component across renders, which is its primary purpose. When you do a `useState`, you can pass the initial value for your state, but that state can henceforth only be changed with the `setState` function. So on first render, your `Container` has `renders` set to `undefined` (the initial property value passed by the parent). When this `props.state` prop is passed in later on, it's not going to change your state.

You should consider not using state in `Container` for this and allow the parent to control it; if `Container` needs the prop to change, you can use a callback instead:

```
function Container({ state: content }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="container">
                {content}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you!What does {state: content} do exactly?

Comment: I was just renaming the `state` prop to a `content` variable since `state` isn't a very descriptive name. As @ConradKay points out, you should consider using a `children` prop instead.

Answer (score 1):

react has a built in prop for passing components to Children `props.children` 
you can pass a component to this prop as so

```
<Child><h1>passing text</h1></Child>
```

And you can access this from the Child like so

```
return (
  <div>{props.children}</div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the other answers address your problem, passing around components to navigate through your app would become messy and difficult to build on top of. Another approach that you should consider is using [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/) which handles the rendering of components for you.

With this package, your code would look something like this:

App:

```
// Node Modules
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

// Page Components
import Home from './Home';
import About from './About';
import Products from './Products';
import Login from './Login';

function App() {
  const [appState, setAppState] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(appState);
  }, [appState])

  return (  
    <div className="App">
      <Nav stateSetter={setAppState}/>
      <Router>
        <Route to="/" component={Home} />
        <Route to="/about" component={About} />
        <Route to="/products" component={Products} />
        <Route to="/login" component={Login} />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Navbar:

```
// Node Modules
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

function Nav(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="Nav" id="nav">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><button><span>App</span></button></li>
            <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/products">Products</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/about">About Us</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/login">Login</li> 
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This will remove the need for you container component and will allow you to organize your page components in a way that is easier to develop on. It will also remove the need to have an `useState()` in your `App` component to keep track of your page components.